# Perform load testing in JMeter with different number of users

Tags: jmeter

I have a question where it might be very easy.
I have to perform load testing on a site(login) with these scenarios.
100 users within 5 minutes
500 users within 5 minutes
1000 users within 5 minutes

I can test each scenario separately by changing the threads in thread group. But what I want to do is run all 3 scenarios one after one automatically. I tried if controller and loop controller but could not fix it. I don't understand where it go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Basic 
[Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) case (JMeter plugin)

You can define several steps with different number of threads (and more configuration)
[image]

If you don't have JMeter plugin yet, you can download plugins-manager.jar and put it into lib/ext directory, then restart JMeter.

Comment: thank you.. when I use ultimate thread group the result is like all mixed up and I have put thread count as 10.. but I get more than 10 results. I don't understand it.                                  I want the results as first 100 threads should run when it finishes again 500 threads should run then again 1000. Is there a way I could do this using controllers? Please help